# Ignore config file with nodeJS/forever

Tags: node.js, forever

Sorry for the (probably) bad question....

I have searched a lot, and have not been able to find a simple example of how to exclude a specific file (or folder, it doesn't matter) from my forever watchlist.

the server runs with forever -w app.js

everytime i update the config file of the app (public/config.json), the server restarts.

All the readmes and explanations are REALLY cryptic and i have NO idea how to use it (from the CLI)

would somebody be so kind and tell me how to start my server without restarting on every update of that file? (no problem to migrate it to a seperate folder, if that is an issue)

thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Forever** - A simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given node script runs continuously. There are two ways to use `forever`: through the command line or by using forever in your code.

**Command Line Usage** -

```
forever [action] [options] SCRIPT
```

There are so many options you can use with forever command. To see this run below command -

```
forever --help
```

When forever command is executed with option `--watch` then any changes made into the file in the project folder or sub-folder, forever restarted script automatically.

**Example -** Let take an example of node.js application.

```
forever --watch app.js
```

For some reason we want to ignore script restart automatically like when any changes made in html views it doesn't restart script.

`--watchIgnore` allow you to ignore pattern when watch is enabled.

**Example -**

```
forever --watch app.js --watchIgnore
```

The forever command used with option --watchIgnore looks `.foreverignore`, if it not found in you project directory then print an error into the console like this -

```
error: Could not read .foreverignore file.
error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'project_folder/.foreverignore'
```

So found such type of error then create a `.foreverignore` file into the project folder with appropriate pattern you want to ignore.

**.foreverignore file sample**

```
node_modules
public
*ignore*
**.log**
```

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue !!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the .foreverignore part @Vikash-Kumar As of v3.0.2 the --watchIgnore is not needed for .foreverignore I guess. The contents in .foreverignore are automatically ignored without the flag --watchIgnore. Infact adding the flag without any additional filtering conditions does not seems to work at all.